# Fortran vectorize log inside a for loop

Tags: fortran

Here is the minimum working code.

```
program test
    implicit none

    double precision:: c1,c2,rate
    integer::ci,cj,cr,cm,i
    integer,parameter::max_iter=10000000 !10^7

    c1=0.0d+0

    CALL system_clock(count_rate=cr)
    CALL system_clock(count_max=cm)
    rate = REAL(cr)

    CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(ci)
    do i=1,max_iter
        c1=c1+log(DBLE(i))
    end do
    CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(cj)
    WRITE(*,*) "system_clock : ",(cj - ci)/rate

    print*, c1
end program test
```

When I compile with `gfortran -Ofast -march=core-avx2 -fopt-info-vec-optimized` the for loop with the log function does not get vectorized. I have also tried with `-O3` but the result does not change.

But if I write the equivalent C++ code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    double c1=0;
    const int max_iter=10000000; // 10^7

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i=1;i<=max_iter;i++)
    {
        c1 += log(i);
    }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start); 
    cout << duration.count() << " ms"<<'\n'; 

    printf("%0.15f\n",c1);

    return 0;
}
```

and compile it with `g++ -Ofast -march=core-avx2 -fopt-info-vec-optimized`, the for loop gets vectorized and runs almost 10 times faster.

What should I do to make the fortran loop vectorized?

Comment: Are you really using `=march=core-avx2` or `\\\` for comments and no program name at the start in Fortran or are you actually using some other code? Which gfortran version and CPU type are you using? I am getting no difference here.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in the post. Now fixed.

Comment: I am using g++-8 and gfortran-8 and CPU i7 8700.

Comment: I do get reported vectorization in gfortan 10. However, I am not seeing any speedup.

Comment: That's weird. On my machine(WSL Ubuntu), the fortran code takes about 127 ms, while the c++ code takes about 14 ms. I have run both of them several times and the result is the same. The answers(value of c1) also agree.

Comment: Check the assembly, it differs https://godbolt.org/z/K9aWDu https://godbolt.org/z/6Jf73F By any speedup I meant in Fortran, I do see speedup in C++. Might be a missed optimization opportunity worth reporting to GCC.  It is strange that I get no vectorization message in godbolt for Fortran because I do get one on my computer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to read assembly code properly yet. I have started learning it very recently. Do you know about any other math libraries in Fortran(aside from mkl, which is kind of my last choice)?

Comment: I would just call the loop in C or C++ and call it from Fortran.

Comment: With a do-loop that won't vectorize, it may be profitable to unroll the loops.  Try `-funroll-loops --param max-unroll-times=4`.  The value of 4 can be adjusted to help/hurt unrolling.  Alternately, if you use Fortran native support for vectors, you could populate a variable `x(1:max_iter)` and do `sum(log(x))`.  This does vectorize.

Comment: I have tried sum(log(x)) already but the result does not change. I have also tried ```-funroll-loops --param max-unroll-times=4``` but same result still.

Comment: @ Vladimir F yeah I can probably do that.

Comment: Odd.  I get vectorization wih gfortran 8, 9, and the upcoming 10.1 on an AMD FX-8350.

Comment: @evets yeah that's odd. do you see any speedup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with vectorizing loops that include the math functions (like `log`) is that the compiler has to be taught the semantics of the vectorized math functions (and you see if you look at the assembler output that the Fortran version calls the "normal" scalar function (a line like `call log`) whereas your C++ version calls the vectorized version (`call _ZGVdN4v___log_finite`)). There has been some work wrt making GFortran understand the glibc vector math library ([libmvec](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec)), but I'm not sure what the current status is. See the thread starting at https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc/2018-04/msg00062.html and continuing in June 2018 starting at https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc/2018-06/msg00167.html for more details.